# Where is database file saved when use pandas to_sql

Tags: pandas, sqlite

I saved my dataframe to sqlite using

```
import sqlite3
cnx = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
df.to_sql(name='myDf', con=cnx)
```

Now I would like to view the data from SQLite browser, but I cant find the databse file. Where does the data stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `:memory:` will not save the database to a file, it will be in **ram** and the database will be lost when the connection is closed.

[In-Memory Databases](https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html)

You need to specify a path as per :-

> database is a path-like object giving the pathname (absolute or
>   relative to the current working directory) of the database file to be
>   opened. You can use ":memory:" to open a database connection to a
>   database that resides in RAM instead of on disk.

[11.13. sqlite3 — DB-API 2.0 interface for SQLite databases](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#module-functions-and-constants)

e.g.

```
cnx = sqlite3.connect('tutorial.db')
```

in which case the database file, tutorial.db, will be in the current working directory.